# how to stop getting DEBUG message on terminal?

Tags: grails

```
DEBUG: Resource: /fancybox/fancybox-y.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer

DEBUG: Resource: /fancybox/fancy_title_over.png - disposition image - rendering disposition 
defer

DEBUG: Resource: /images/shadow.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer

DEBUG: Resource: /js/jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/images/ui-bg_highlight-
hard_100_f2f5f7_1x100.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer
DEBUG: Resource: /js/jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_deedf7_1x100.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer

DEBUG: Resource: /js/jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/images/ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer

DEBUG: Resource: /js/jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/images/ui-bg_glass_100_e4f1fb_1x400.png - disposition image - rendering disposition defer
```

I want to stop getting this

> **DEBUG** message

each time i am browsing my application. Is there any thing to be checked to stop this? Any solution for this problem would be appreciated. Thank you! in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the logger level configuration to INFO  from DEBUG in whatever logger you are using(See [Common Log Levels](http://www.allapplabs.com/log4j/log4j_levels.htm) ). If it is the grails builtin logging you might want to check in Config.groovy file in the log4j section